# Cannot get IF statements to update TextBlock from ComboBox Selection C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, if-statement

I am trying to get a return back to the main program but it has to change on the ComboBox change. No matter what it is returning whatever the String is set to at the top of the class. If I change `the result = ""`; to `result = "Test"`; it will display `Test` in the TextBox I am trying to update. But it won't get anything from the IF statements.

Thanks for the help!

MAIN PROGRAM

```
namespace VTCPT
{
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();


        }

        private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
              //UPDATE THE SHORTCODE TEXTBLOCK
            updateVTCShortCode display = new updateVTCShortCode();
            display.mergeShortCode(longFormCodec.SelectedItem.ToString());
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(display.finalResult()))
                { shortFormCodec.Text = ".."; }
            else { shortFormCodec.Text = display.finalResult(); }
            }

        private void updateShortForm(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {

        }


        private void TextBlock_SelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {


        }

        private void fsSiteBuild_SelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
        }


        private void updateSiteBuild(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            int index = fsRoomDesig.Text.IndexOf(".");

            if (index > 0)
            { fsSiteBuild.Text = fsRoomDesig.Text.Substring(0, index); }
            else { fsSiteBuild.Text = ".."; }
        }

        private void vtcSystemName_SelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }     
    }
}
```

updateVTCShortCode CLASS

```
namespace VTCPT
{
    class updateVTCShortCode
    {
        String result = "";  //////ALWAYS RESULTS ONLY IN WHAT IS HERE
        public void mergeShortCode(String longFormCodec)
         {

            if (longFormCodec == "Cisco SX80")
            {
                String sendShortForm = "SX80";
                result = "V-T" + sendShortForm;

            }
            if (longFormCodec == "Cisco Webex Codec Plus")
            {
                String sendShortForm = "SRK";
                result = "V-T" + sendShortForm;
            }
            if (longFormCodec == "Cisco Webex Codec Pro")
            {
                String sendShortForm = "SRK";
                result = "V-T" + sendShortForm;
            }
    }
        public String finalResult()
        { return result; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try printing out the longFormCodec string right when you enter the function. I suspect that might be causing the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not doing the string comparisons correctly. You need to use .equals() for strings.

You need to replace all the string comparisons where you are using == to .equals() and it will work:

```
namespace VTCPT
{
    class updateVTCShortCode
    {
        String result = "";  //////ALWAYS RESULTS ONLY IN WHAT IS HERE
        public void mergeShortCode(String longFormCodec)
         {

            if (longFormCodec.equals("Cisco SX80"))
            {
                String sendShortForm = "SX80";
                result = "V-T" + sendShortForm;

            }
            if (longFormCodec.equals("Cisco Webex Codec Plus"))
            {
                String sendShortForm = "SRK";
                result = "V-T" + sendShortForm;
            }
            if (longFormCodec.equals("Cisco Webex Codec Pro"))
            {
                String sendShortForm = "SRK";
                result = "V-T" + sendShortForm;
            }
    }
        public String finalResult()
        { return result; }
    }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate that.  Apparently though I was incorrect.  I am not passing anything back to the return finalResult().  I'm still going through training and this is my starter app so thank you very much for the help.

Comment: @Shawn no problem. I am glad that I could help you. If this answer helped you please mark it as the answer to your question and consider upvoting it.

Comment: I'm not getting the result sent back to the main program.  Do you have any suggestions there?  :-) I'll leave you alone about that.  Thanks again.

Comment: @Shawn I am not seeing where your code could be causing issues. Try running the debugger and look if you are entering the if statements. I suspect that there is something going wrong with the if statements, for some reason they aren't being executed.